# Matched Geometry Effect with ForEach

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I have a quite simple scenario, a list with ForEach of thumbnails (ElementView), and if you click on one it opens as a full screen detail view (DetailView). I'd like to use the matchedGeometryEffect for that, to achieve a hero animation. It's almost working well, but the animation is still not perfect, looks like if the two views were handled separately.

**CollectionView.swift**

```
struct CollectionView: View {
    var data = [
        "Test card 1",
        "Test card 2",
        "Test card 3",
        "Test card 4",
        "Test card 5"
    ]

    @State var selectedElement: String?

    @Namespace var namespace

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if selectedElement == nil {
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem()]){
                        ForEach(data.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                            ElementView(text: data[idx])
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: idx, in: namespace, properties: .position)
                                .transition(.scale)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    withAnimation {
                                        selectedElement = data[idx]
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ForEach(data.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                    if data[idx] == selectedElement {
                        DetailView(
                            text: selectedElement!,
                            backDidTap: {
                                withAnimation { selectedElement = nil }
                            }
                        )
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: idx, in: namespace, properties: .position)
                            .transition(.scale)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ElementView.swift**

```
struct ElementView: View {
    let text: String
    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack(spacing: .zero) {
            Color.black
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2)
            Text(text)
                .padding(.top, 8)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2)
        }
    }
}
```

**DetailView.swift**

```
struct DetailView: View {
    let text: String
    let backDidTap: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
       VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: .zero) {
           Color.black
               .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
               .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2)
               .onTapGesture {
                   backDidTap()
               }
           Text(text)
               .padding(.top, 8)
               .padding(.leading, 8)
           Spacer()
       }
    }
}
```

Outcome with "Slow animations" enabled on simulator:
https://i.imgur.com/hW4qR6t.mp4

I think something is not right with the transition, but I can't figure out what. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63097922/using-swiftuis-matchedgeometryeffect-in-complex-ui) already, as the issue is quite similar, but this custom transition didn't work for me.

Comment: Don't use indexes, use unique data related identifiers for id argument.

Comment: I am, I just wanted to make the example as simple as possible. Same result with UUID-s as id-s in the matchedGeometryEffect parameter.

Comment: The problem you are having is that SwiftUI does not know how to animate your detail view, so it is guessing and guessing wrong. Here is a great [tutorial](https://swiftui-lab.com/matchedgeometryeffect-part1/) on `matchedGeometryEffect` and hero animations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have already found the answer, but here is my solution:

**The problem is that you are removing the original view with the if else condition in your rootview.** So swiftUI does not now what was the original state of the view animation. Here is my solution:

```
struct CollectionView: View {
    var data = [
        "Test card 1",
        "Test card 2",
        "Test card 3",
        "Test card 4",
        "Test card 5"
    ]

    @State var selectedElement: String?

    @Namespace var namespace

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem()]){
                        ForEach(data.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                            ElementView(text: data[idx])
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: data[idx], in: namespace, properties: .position)
                                //.transition(.scale)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    withAnimation {
                                        selectedElement = data[idx]
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .zIndex(1)
            
            if let selected = selectedElement {
                DetailView(text: selected, backDidTap: {
                    withAnimation { selectedElement = nil }
                })
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: selected, in: namespace)
                    //.transition(.scale)
                    .zIndex(2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```